# Execution failed for task ':checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

I am trying Admob mediation, during build I'm getting these errors. 
'''Execution failed for task ':checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.

> 1 exception was raised by workers:
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.FastSafeIterableMap found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$AscendingIterator found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$DescendingIterator found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$Entry found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$IteratorWithAdditions found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$ListIterator found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$SupportRemove found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.util.Function found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.ArrayMap found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.ArrayMap$1 found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.ArraySet found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.ArraySet$1 found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.CircularArray found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.CircularIntArray found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.ContainerHelpers found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.LongSparseArray found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.LruCache found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections$ArrayIterator found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections$EntrySet found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections$KeySet found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections$MapIterator found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections$ValuesCollection found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.SimpleArrayMap found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.collection.SparseArrayCompat found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$1 found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$PermissionCompatDelegate found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$RequestPermissionsRequestCodeValidator found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl$1 found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityManagerCompat found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityOptionsCompat found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityOptionsCompat$ActivityOptionsCompatImpl found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.AlarmManagerCompat found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.AppComponentFactory found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.AppLaunchChecker found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.AppOpsManagerCompat found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.BundleCompat found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.BundleCompat$BundleCompatBaseImpl found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity$ExtraData found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory$CompatWrapped found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.FrameMetricsAggregator found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.FrameMetricsAggregator$FrameMetricsApi24Impl found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.FrameMetricsAggregator$FrameMetricsApi24Impl$1 found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.FrameMetricsAggregator$FrameMetricsBaseImpl found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.FrameMetricsAggregator$MetricType found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CompatJobEngine found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CompatWorkEnqueuer found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CompatWorkItem found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$GenericWorkItem found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$JobServiceEngineImpl found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$JobServiceEngineImpl$WrapperWorkItem found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$JobWorkEnqueuer found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$WorkEnqueuer found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NavUtils found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationBuilderWithBuilderAccessor found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Action found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Action$Builder found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Action$Extender found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Action$SemanticAction found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Action$WearableExtender found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$BadgeIconType found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$BigPictureStyle found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$BigTextStyle found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Builder found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$CarExtender found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$CarExtender$UnreadConversation found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$CarExtender$UnreadConversation$Builder found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$DecoratedCustomViewStyle found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1)
>     Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Extender found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and '''